# Using @EnvironmentObject I get: "Cannot assign to property: 'viewModel' is a get-only property"

Tags: swift, swiftui

I get the error

> Cannot assign to property: 'viewModel' is a get-only property
>   When trying to use @EnvironmentObject of generic type.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

protocol HasCount {
    var count: Int { get set }
    var countPublished: Published<Int> { get set }
    var countPublisher: Published<Int>.Publisher { get set }
}

struct SomeView<ViewModelType: ObservableObject & HasCount>: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModelType

    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            Text("text")
            .onAppear {
                self.viewModel.count = 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `HasCount` protocol has to be restricted to objects only as below

```
protocol HasCount: AnyObject { // << here !
    var count: Int { get set }
    var countPublished: Published<Int> { get set }
    var countPublisher: Published<Int>.Publisher { get set }
}
```

Comment: This is correct, or just "HasCount: class" which is also enough in my case at least

Comment: how does this answer the question? How do u re-set the viewModel @EnvironmentObject?